# Is "that" needed in "I saw that you were waiting..."?

Tags: grammar, optional-that

Can someone confirm with me for these sentences

- "I saw you were waiting for the bus"  —    incorrect
- "I saw that you were waiting for the bus"  — correct

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct. I think the first one is used more in speech.